# Convert GML file to adjacency matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, graph, adjacency-matrix, graph-modelling-language

I have a [GML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_Modelling_Language) file of a directed graph ([Political blogs](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~mejn/netdata/polblogs.zip)). I want to use this graph in Matlab as an adjacency matrix. How can I convert it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a sample code [`here`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/15318) for this purpose:

```
%Extracting edges from gml file graph
fileName = 'dolphins.gml';
inputfile = fopen(fileName);
A=[];
l=0;
k=1;
while 1
      % Get a line from the input file
      tline = fgetl(inputfile);
      % Quit if end of file
      if ~ischar(tline)
          break
      end
      nums = regexp(tline,'\d+','match');
      if length(nums)
          if l==1
              l=0;
              A(k,2)=str2num(nums{1});  
              k=k+1;
              continue;
          end
          A(k,1)=str2num(nums{1});
          l=1;
      else
          l=0;
          continue;
      end
end
```

`A[]`, an `[m x 2]` matrix, contains the links between nodes.

Comment: Thanks to answer to newcomer :) .I check the code it seems to work.But Online converter loading till now and I don't see the result in it!!!

Comment: @Fatime, you're right. I tried the online converter myself and it stuck at something. But I think it's better to parse your graph inside MATLAB rather than relying on an online one.

Comment: Thanks again,I wanted to check it and compare the result because the number of edges was different from  the result of gephi graph software but I think there are some parallel links(https://gephi.org/) The Matlab code works.

Answer (score 0):

With R you can use:

```
library("multiplex") ## >v1.5 
read.gml(file, as="matrix")
```