# create a graph with too many edges

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I have 100 nodes and 4950 edges. What is the fastest way to create a graph in Python (not planning at all to visualize or draw it) so that I can have access to node information so that I would need what each item in the 2d matrix mean by saying node 1 is connected to node 3? (also I don't need to save it as matrix).

```
import gensim
import nltk
from gensim.models import word2vec
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import logging
import re
import itertools
import glob
from collections import defaultdict
import networkx as nx


logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(message)s',
                    level=logging.INFO)

sentences = word2vec.Text8Corpus("/home/mona/mscoco/text8")
model = word2vec.Word2Vec(sentences, workers = 16)
#model.init_sims(replace = True)
model_name = "text8_data"
model.save(model_name)

stopwords = nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english')

path = "/home/mona/mscoco/caption_files/*.txt"
files = glob.glob(path)
adj_list = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: 0))


for file in files:
        g.add_nodes(file)

for file1, file2 in itertools.combinations(files, 2):
        with open(file1) as f1:
                f1_text = f1.read()
                f1_words = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]", ' ', f1_text).lower().split()
                f1_words = [w for w in f1_words if w not in stopwords]
                print(f1_text)
                f1.close()
        with open(file2) as f2:
                f2_text = f2.read()
                f2_words = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]", ' ', f2_text).lower().split()
                f2_words = [w for w in f2_words if w not in stopwords]
                print(f2_text)
                f2.close()
        print('{0}: {1}: {2}'.format(file1, file2, model.wmdistance(f1_words, f2_words)))
        g.add_edge(file1, file2, model.wmdistance(f1_words, f2_words))



print(g.number_of_edges())
print(g.number_of_edges())


nx.write_gml(g, "gensim.gml")
```

Please let me know if you have better suggestion that my current code. I will eventually have something like 20 nodes and 190 edges. I am mostly looking for something that processing its output would be easy to another program like MATLAB. I am not sure if .gml files are easy to process in MATLAB.

Comment: With that density of edges it would make more sense to store the pairs of nodes that *aren't* connected.

Comment: This question is too open ended. How are you getting the list of nodes and edges? An adjacency matrix, list of nodes with connections to their neighbors, a list of pairs representing an edge are all valid options...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the most efficient graph data structure in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171/what-is-the-most-efficient-graph-data-structure-in-python)

Comment: each node is a file name and the edge is the similarity score between them.  @jaypb I have been thinking of defaultdict for creating an adjacency list but I am not sure if that's a good solution. I will have a complete graph.

Comment: @jaypb so nodes are like `/home/mona/mscoco/caption_files/test/captions_broccoli467145.txt` and  `/home/mona/mscoco/caption_files/test/captions_orange137230.txt`  and edge is like: 0.825396825397

Comment: @JohnColeman: With that density of edges, there *are* no pairs of nodes that aren't connected.

Comment: You could use a dictionary keyed by pairs of nodes where the value stored is the similarity score.

Answer (score 1):

I think generating a GML file for the precise purpose of reusing in Matlab is probably fine. This question has some more information about that.

[Convert GML file to adjacency matrix in matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15918791/convert-gml-file-to-adjacency-matrix-in-matlab#15919696)

Comment: please have a look at the update question with code :)

Comment: Hopefully my new answer is helpful, and you learned an important lesson about giving enough information in your question. The question as it now stands is completely different than before :).